# How to add plugin custom field to custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have used a plugin called [Amazon product in a post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amazon-product-in-a-post-plugin/). It works okay with posts type. It adds custom fields in the posts page. But, I have made another custom post type called products. It does not work with that. I want the custom field appear in Products post type.

I have used few suggestions.
[Adding plugin in custom posts type](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-amazon-product-in-a-post-plugin-feature-suggestion-custom-post-types) but it did not work for me.

I have googled, tried several plugins but none of these seems to work. Can anyone suggest me another plugin or any other way to solve my purpose. What I want to do is, add amazon selected books to my website, in my custom post type pages. I have tried adding

```
if(function_exists('amazonProductInAPostBox1')){
    global $appipBulidBox;
    $custom_post_type = 'put-post-type-here';
    add_action('admin_menu', create_function("$appipBulidBox",
"if( function_exists( 'add_meta_box' ))add_meta_box( 'amazonProductInAPostBox1',
__( 'Amazon Product In a Post Settings', 'appplugin' ), 'amazonProductInAPostBox1', $custom_post_type, 'normal', 'high' );"));
}
```

But It did not seem to work. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure you can use the variable `$custom_post_type` inside the newly created function without providing it as argument/paramenter. Try including it after the first (and only) argument `$appipBulidBox` (which is not being used so far...?).

Comment: I did not understand exactly what you mean by that? Can you tell me clearly.?

Comment: Well, I meant just to replace your `add_action` with this `add_action('admin_menu', create_function("$appipBulidBox, $custom_post_type",
"if( function_exists( 'add_meta_box' ))add_meta_box( 'amazonProductInAPostBox1',
__( 'Amazon Product In a Post Settings', 'appplugin' ), 'amazonProductInAPostBox1', $custom_post_type, 'normal', 'high' );"));`. I haven't tested that and I don't really get what you want to do (or what your problem is), but maybe that way you have access to the variable `$custom_post_type`. Anyway, what is the other argument `$appipBulidBox` for? You don't seem to use it.

Comment: NO luck. I want to add amazon products to my website. I add products to my website through custom post type called 'Products'. So, I have been trying to activate plugin for that custom post type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suresh
what is the custom post type you want to hook into?
You need to make sure you change the $custom_post_type = 'put-post-type-here'; line to be the actual custom post type **slug** you want to hook it into. Then, I would suggest adding the function to the functions.php.
And try it this way:

```
add_action('admin_menu','new_appip_custom_post_type_metabox');
function new_appip_custom_post_type_metabox(){
     if(function_exists('amazonProductInAPostBox1') && function_exists( 'add_meta_box')){
         add_meta_box( 'amazonProductInAPostBox1','Amazon Product In a Post Settings', 'amazonProductInAPostBox1', 'put-post-type-here', 'normal', 'high' );
     }
     return;
}
```